# Print HeaderEvent parameter from hasHeader callback function

Tags: ibm-doors

I have the following function that prepares a canvas for headers

```
hasHeader(canv,cb);
```

cb function has the following structure

```
void cb(DBE el, HeaderEvent event, int hIndex, int param) {
   // do something
}
```

I know that event can be headerResize, headerEdit, headerSelect or headerReorder but my question is how can I print this parameter I order to see his value? I guess it is possible somehow but I cannot figure out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, HeaderEvent actually ends up being more like an enumeration. Take a look at the following:

```
// Set the current module
Module m = current

// Redraw function for canvas - required (empty for this example)
void reDraw ( DBE canv ) {

}

// Header callback function
void cb ( DBE el , HeaderEvent event, int hIndex, int param ) {
    // Header Event Cases
    if ( event == headerEdit ) {
        print "HeaderEdit" "\t" hIndex "\n"
    }
    if ( event == headerResize ) {
        print "HeaderResize" "\t" param "\n"
    }
    if ( event == headerSelect ) {
        print "HeaderSelect" "\t" hIndex "\n"
    }   
    if ( event == headerReorder ) {
        print "HeaderReorder" "\t" hIndex "\t" param "\n"
    }
}

// Create the Main Window and Callbacks
DB main_DB = create ( m , "Header Test" , styleSubWindow | styleFloating )
DBE canv_DBE = canvas ( main_DB , 100 , 100 , reDraw )
// Prep for headers
hasHeader ( canv_DBE , cb )

// Realize the dialog box - required before adding columns to the canvas
realize mainDB

// Add canvas columns
headerAddColumn ( canvas_test , "Header Test 1" , 100 )
headerAddColumn ( canvas_test , "Header Test 2" , 100 )

// Show the dialog box
show mainDB
```

As you click on the headers and drag them around, you'll get the feedback from the event case structure.

I don't see an easier way to implement this, but someone else might have more insight than me!

Comment: Ok, firstly thank you for answering. Secondly, in your example and in my script too resizing is done only for the first time, for example if I want to modify "Header Test 2" to 150 there is no problem("HeaderResize  150" will be printed), but then if I want to resize "Header Test 1" or "Header Test 2" the width of the column changes visually but no message is printed...looks like the cb function has not been called.

Comment: When I resize the column header, I get the message each time- but the message is not produced if I resize the Dialog Box. Also, the DXL Interaction / DXL output window might not scroll down to show the new print statements- this may make it look like nothing is being reported.

Comment: I see that depends on the version of the doors used, could you tell me what version do you use?

Comment: 9.6.1.6 is my current operating version.